# Finding the second table name which is having a many to many relation

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

With the given query I am able to find one to one & one to many relation which the given table is having

```sql
SELECT distinct table_name, column_name, referenced_table_name, referenced_column_name 
from information_schema.key_column_usage 
where constraint_schema='schema_name' 
AND table_schema='schema_name'
AND referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL 
and (table_name LIKE  '%potential%' or referenced_table_name LIKE '%potential%' )
```

how can I find the table name which is having many to many relation with the given table ..

Comment: *how can I find the table name which is having many to many relation with the given table ..* M:N needs intermediate junction table - i.e. you must find the chain of 3 tables (including starting one) where the table in the middle is joined to both outer tables as N:1. Use 2 copies of your query joined.

Comment: I didn't got you can you please elaborate a little more I just want to know all the table names which is having relation with given table..

Comment: Imagine that you remove the condition which specifies table_name. The query will give you all pairs (table A refers to table B). If you need to find M:N relation then you must find 2 such pairs where 2 different tables A1 and A2 refers to the same table B.